# I need help deploying my application with monodevelop. ERROR: The application was terminated by a signal: SIGIO

Tags: xamarin.ios

Does anybody have any idea why I am getting this error when I try to debug on my iPhone?

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -installdev="/Volumes/User Storage/Users/Robert/Projects/DinnerReady/DinnerReady/bin/iPhone/Debug/DinnerReady.app"
Please ensure your device is connected...
Connected to: Robert?s iPhone
Initializing file service...
Uploading application
Finalizing file service...
Connected to: Robert?s iPhone
Installing application
The application was terminated by a signal: SIGIO
```

At first I thought I may have done the provisioning wrong, but I can deploy applications using Xcode.  Thanks!

Here is the console output:

```
Sat Jan 29 00:11:29 unknown lockdownd[16] <Error>: 2ff66000 handle_connection: Could not receive USB message #10 from mtouch. Killing connection
Sat Jan 29 00:11:29 unknown lockdownd[16] <Error>: 2ffe8000 handle_connection: Could not receive USB message #6 from mtouch. Killing connection
Sat Jan 29 00:11:29 unknown com.apple.mobile.lockdown[16] <Notice>: Could not receive size of messageCould not receive size of message
Sat Jan 29 00:11:29 unknown mobile_installation_proxy[1334] <Error>: main: Could not receive request from host.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because I had a space in one of the directory names above the solution.

Comment: Thx a lot. This answer saved my day. Just 10 minutes before the customer meeting :)